# Почему функция не возвращает строку?

Tags: c++, c

```
char* take_module_name()
{
    TCHAR FilePath[MAX_PATH + 1]; // буфер для имени файла
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, FilePath, sizeof(FilePath) / sizeof(FilePath[0]));

    int lastSlash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH + 1; i++)
    {
        if (FilePath[i] == '\\' || FilePath[i] == '/')lastSlash = i;
    }

    
    char filename[40];
    strcpy(filename, &FilePath[lastSlash + 1]);
    filename[39] = '\0';

    return  filename;
}
```

Почему когда я вызываю эту функцию она не выводит имя файла, хотя filename в функции выводится нормально?
Вызываю так:

```
cout << take_module_name();
```

Хотя если так делать то все работает, но через раз:

```
string file_way = (string)OBF("DEL /q %systemroot%\\Prefetch\\") + take_module_name();
cout << file_way;
```

P.s как оказалось цикл иногда возвращает неправильный lastSlash ,но почему ,для меня непонятно.

Comment: а как вы вызываете?

Comment: потому что массив `filename` находится на стеке и после завершения функции он уничтожается...

Comment: @Fat-Zer а как тогда правильно сделать?

Comment: и какое значение имеет lastSlash после цикла, чтобы потом копировать из  &FilePath[lastSlash + 1]?...

Comment: на выбор: выделить память в куче с помощью `malloc`/`new`; передать в функцию указатель на область памяти, в которую будет записано возвращаемое значение; вернуть указатель на статический мсассив; (для плюсов) вернуть объект-строку (`std::string`).

Comment: а если изменить `char* take_module_name() {}` на  `string take_module_name() {}`?

Comment: @azlov странно,но тоже не работает,но почему тогда когда string возвращаем он тоже не выводится?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan заметил особенность,иногда lastSlash возвращает неправельно значение,но почему непонятно

Comment: @Fat-Zer мне кажется стек тут не причем,потому что если поменять на string ничего не поменяется

Comment: @Whitehorse, нуда... в цикле поиска тоже ошибка...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да,только в чем она заключается,и как так получается что через раз выводит правильное значение

Comment: @Whitehorse, намекну: может оказаться так, что возвращённый путь будет меньше `MAX_PATH`... ну и разумно было бы искать последний слеш с конца...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О возврате указателя на локальную переменную уже написал @Ildar. Но в коде есть ещё одна ошибка -  в следующем коде

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH + 1; i++)
{
    if (FilePath[i] == '\\' || FilePath[i] == '/')lastSlash = i;
}
```

Дело в том, что строка `FilePath` может быть короткой, а в конце массива будет мусор. и там вполне могут быть символы слеша. Как исправить? Можно подсунуть правильную длину вместо `MAX_PATH+1`, но я так понимаю, это не интересно.

Можно так

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH + 1; i++)
{
    if (FilePath[i] == '\\' || FilePath[i] == '/')lastSlash = i;
    if (FilePath[i] == 0) break; // достигли нулевого символа - выходим.
}
```

А можно просто занулить весь массив изначально.

Comment: А ещё можно засунуть проверку на ноль в условие цикла: `for (int i = 0; FilePath[i]; i++)`

Comment: А можно посмотреть, что пытается сделать автор вопроса (а он хочет получить имя файла с полного пути) и просто предложить готовую функцию [PathFindFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindfilenamea)

Answer (score 1):

1. изменяем `string` переданный по ссылке

   ```
    void foo(std::string& message)
    {
      message = "hello";
    }
   ```
2. возвращаем `string`

   ```
    std::string foo()
    {
      std::string message = "hello";
      return message;
    }
   ```
3. изменяем массив char переданный в функцию

   ```
    void foo(char* message)
    {
      strcpy_s(message, 6, "hello");
    }
   ```
4. возвращаем указатель на динамический массив char выделенный в функции, но это очень плохой вариант, так как нужно чтобы кто-то снаружи зачистил память

   ```
    char* foo()
    {
      char* message = new char[6];
      strcpy_s(message, 6, "hello");
      return message;
    }
   ```

также рекомендую использовать функцию `strcpy_s` вместо `strcpy` так как c помощью неё вы будете уверены сколько символов вы записываете в целевую строку и избежите переполнения буфера если строка-источник длинней результирующей строки

Comment: тут проблема не в том каким образом мы возвращаем значение,а в том что lastSlash почему-то иногда возвращается неправильный

Comment: @Whitehorse на часть вопроса думаю ответил

Comment: `const char[]` обычно называют C-строкой

Comment: @dIm0n как правильнее назвать в моем случае?

Comment: @Ildar так и назвать — массив char-ов/символов :) Внутри функции уже можно говорить указатель

Answer (score 0):

К ответу KoVadim, хотел бы добавить, что  у вас есть ошибка при передаче аргументов в функцию `strcpy`, вторым аргументом которого должен быть const char*, а вы передаете `TCHAR*`. Я бы предложил:

```
const std::string take_module_name()
{
    TCHAR FilePath[MAX_PATH + 1];  
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, FilePath, MAX_PATH);    
    int lastSlash = 0;       
    for (int i = 0; FilePath[i] != L'\0'; i++)
    {
        if (FilePath[i] == '\\' || FilePath[i] == '/')lastSlash = i;
    }
    return std::string( (char*)&FilePath[lastSlash + 1]);    
}
```

Comment: замечание конечно хорошее, но вот строка `return std::string( (char*)&FilePath[lastSlash + 1]); ` просто перечеркивает понимание TCHAR

Comment: а ещё, если придираться, то и символы `\0`, `\\` и '/' стоило обернуть в `_T()`, а не делать один длинным, а остальные короткими...

Comment: @KoVadim, ну что делать, а если человек хочет возвращать именно  указатель на  char,?

Comment: Тогда нужно конвертировать правильно.